# How to handle UnhandledAlertException in selenium java ?(UnhandledAlertException Only)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

At any where of my application i am getting incomplete reply from server pop up ,But i don't know where i will get that popup

should accept Popup/Alert

(UnhandledAlertException Only)

My Error is :

org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: Incomplete reply from server
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-50ENJGQ1', ip: '10.0.0.58', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: Can you consider to bump up Selenium to v3.4.0? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest try to analyse UI steps manually . And you can try this in your code , if you find after or before which step you are getting any kind of alert.

```
try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println(driver.switchTo().alert().getText());
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //exception handling
    }
```

Please provide some more information regarding to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to accept or decline the alert box. Without doing so, it is not possible to capture screenshot. The `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` is thrown when you do not deal with the alert box.

Following is the way how I handle this exception.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String alertText = alert.getText();
System.out.println("ERROR: (ALERT BOX DETECTED) - ALERT MSG : " + alertText);
alert.accept();
```